# Coefficient in the binomial expansion

Tags: sequences-and-series

> What is the coefficient of $t^{-5}$ in  $\left(2t+\frac1{t^2}\right)^{10}$?

I arranged into the form $10C_k\, 2t^{10-k}\,t^{-2k}$ and then for $k=5$ I got $8064$, but it turns out the answer was 0?

What have i done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

What you did is correct, the answer is $8064$. You can check the expansion on [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expand+(2t%2B1%2Ft%5E2)%5E%7B10%7D).